# Trigger SQL creation (prevent a date within a date range from being entered into database)

Tags: mysql, sql

How I create a trigger which doesn't allow me to introduce some dates between a time slot? Thanks

Comment: Please provide examples and a more specific questions

Answer (score 3):

if you want to throw an error when some date is between a timeslot you could do something like this (as an example).

```
create table myTable(id int,datefield datetime);

create trigger date_check before insert on myTable
for each row
begin
  IF new.datefield BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Date Not Allowed";
  END IF;
end/
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a1505/1

This trigger will throw an error when user tries to insert a date within 2015 into database.

You can create another trigger for `before update` as well so if user tries to update it to a date within your time slot i'll throw an error as well.